# Trouble with loading javascript into IE8

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm stuck on a problem. I have my index.php which include html code following the user who are log on.

For exemple if a user are defined to be a "demandeur", then index.php will load "demandeur.php". There are a jquery script file and css file which are loaded by "demandeur.php". Everything are loaded and work correctly with Firefox but on IE8 impossible to load it correctly because I get the error "is null or not an object." each time.

resume :

```
index.php whith[debug.js, bootstrap.js, jquery.js]  --> include (demandeur.php with [demandeurScript.js, demandeur.css])
```

When demandeurScript.js call a function inside debug.js for exemple i get the error "debug is null or not an object."

---

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">

        <title>OAPTHD</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.hideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.gritter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=blablabla&sensor=false&extension=.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->


    </head>

    <body>



        <!-- Chargement de la page demandée -->
        <?php include("./php/authentification/verifieLogin.php");?>





    </body>
</html>

</html>
```

---

verifielogin.php

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
include('php/log.php');

session_start();
log_php("_SESSION[login] = " . $_SESSION['login']);
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])){ 
    log_php("Aucune session init, redirection vers formulaire.php");
    header ("location: ./php/pages/formulaire.php");
    exit();
} else {
    switch ($_SESSION['droitUtilisateur']) {
        case "4":
        log_php("include de ./php/pages/demandeur.php");
        include("./php/pages/demandeur.php");

        //exit();
        break;
        case "3":
        log_php("include de ./php/pages/valideur.php");
        include("./php/pages/valideur.php");
        //exit();
        break;
        case "2":
        log_php("include de ./php/pages/c2eupr.php");
        include("./php/pages/c2eupr.php");
        //exit();
        break;
        default:
        log_php("include de ./index.php");
        include("location: ./index.php");
        //exit();

    }
}

?>
```

---

demandeur.php

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/fileUploader.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/demandeur.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div id ="home" class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">OAPTHD</a>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" id="menuHome" class="lienMenu">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle lienMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Etudes<b class="caret" class="lienMenu"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="ulDropdownEtudes">

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle lienMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Mes Demandes<b class="caret" class="lienMenu"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#mesDemandes" id="menuToutes" class="dropdownMesDemandes">Toutes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#mesDemandes" id="menuEnCours" class="dropdownMesDemandes">En cours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#mesDemandes" id="menuFinalisees" class="dropdownMesDemandes">Finalisées</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a id="labelNomUtilisateur" ></a></li>

                    <li><a id="boutonDeconnection">Déconnection</a></li>
                    <li><a id="boutonAide">Aide</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Application OAPTHD !!!</h1>
        <p>
            <?php
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$heure = date("H:i");
Print("<em>Bonjour, Nous sommes le $date et il est $heure</em>");
            ?>
        </p>
        <p>This is a TEST template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-ttc btn-lg" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

    <div id ="demandes" class="row">


    </div>


    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy;  - 
            <a href="#"></a>
            - 
            <a href="#" target='_blank'>Pawlak Steven</a>
        </p>
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logoS" name="logo" width="83" height="36" id="logoOBS">
    </footer>


</div> <!-- /container -->
<script src="scripts/demandeurScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

How to go through it ?
Thank you,
best regards.

Comment: You have two </html> tags at the end of your file. It can cause some troubles

Comment: Thx for pick up this mistake, but it wasn't that :/